# Server - Run a program allowing it to write only on a specific directory

Tags: server, permissions, users

i'm a web developer and i need to run some third-party programs on my server. Since these programs are **third-party** and i'm not always 100% sure of their reliability, i would run these programs with specific permissions. Since these programs will need to write file to disk, i want to set up permissions to deny access to the entire hard disk (i dont want even read-only), except for one directory where these programs will write into. 
I thought that the easiest way to achieve this is:

- create the group "third-parties"
- create the user "third-parties-user"
- deny access to the entire hard disk (even not read-only) to group "third-parties"
- allow read-write into `/var/example/thirdparties`
- set "third-parties-user" as the owner of the programs i have to run
- write a cronjob under "third-parties-user" to start programs at startup (something like `@reboot sh /var/example/thirdparties/run-all-thirdparties-programs.sh` )

My question is..technically talking, how can i create those group/user and set up permissions? **if i run a program owned by specific user, will that program inherit permissions from his owner group/user?**
i'm completely new in Ubuntu Server..

Also.. if anyone has a better idea to reach my goal, i have big ears :)
thanks

Comment: FYI: That's the standard proceedure on *NIX systems - don't trust something you don't have to. You only share group privileges (by adding multiple sytem users running the services to a group) if necessary (e.g. if you would want a service to use `dovecot`'s SASL authentication). `upstart` runs as user `root` and privileges don't need to be dropped to a specific uid/gid, but can be dropped to individual uids/gids per service. Ubuntu 15.04 runs `systemd`, so you might want to write `systemd` scripts rather than (not too) soon to be deprecated `upstart` scripts.

Comment: Sorry but your answer it's not so clear to me.. as i told, im new in Ubuntu server. Also, i'm going to run all with 14.04 LTS server . With upstart you meant the cronjob "@reboot"? thanks for your interest

Comment: @JhonZunda those apps are web-based or local?

Comment: It's not an answer, but a comment. I read `upstart`, but you wrote startup and thought you already know it. Make yourself familiar with [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) or wait for a detailed answer.

Comment: @KarlRichter ok thanks for your link, im going to make me familiar, still waiting for a detailed answer. NewUSer those apps are local.. they basically are API client.. they will take some values from outside the server and then write them (the values) locally.. i need to keep them always open.

Answer (score 0):

The standard permission system in Linux does not support well the use case that you are describing (for example "deny access to the entire hard-disk"). A better approach would be to try using `chroot` or `docker`, to make sure that the program runs in an environment that is isolated from the main system.